# Geometric Interpretation of System of Equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, 3d

Perhaps I am overlooking something but this is puzzling me.

I have a system of equations which can be represented by three planes:

\begin{align}
\Pi_1&: \ x-7y+5z=3\\
\Pi_2&: \ x-y+3z=-1\\
\Pi_3&: \ 3y-z=k
\end{align}

I have made an augmented matrix in echelon form:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-7&5&3\\
  0&-6&2&4\\
  0&0&0&2k+4\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Now consider when this system of equations has infinite solutions. It should be when $2k+4=0\implies k=-2$, right? Then either $0x=0$ or $0y=0$ or $0z=0$ which is always true.

Furthermore notice that $\Pi_3$ is actually a linear combination of $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ (when $k=-2$) because $\Pi_3=\frac{1}{2}\Pi_2 - \frac{1}{2}\Pi_1$. Doesn't this mean that $\Pi_3$ passes through the solution set of $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$?

If the solution set is indeed infinite, the intersection between these three planes should be one line. However when I check on GeoGebra and it shows this:

[image: GeoGebra]

which means I am incorrect. What am I missing here? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three planes do indeed intersect in a line when $k=-2$. Check what it is that you actually graphed in GeoGebra. It looks to me like the third plane in your image is $3x-y=-2$ instead of $3y-z=-2$. The latter is not orthogonal to the $x$-$y$ plane as the plane in your image is.

[image: Intersecting planes]

We can verify this intersection by using the Plücker matrix of the intersection line of the first two planes. One parameterization of this line is $\frac13(-5,-2,0)+\lambda(-8,1,3)$. In homogeneous coordinates, then, this line is the join of $\mathbf p = (-5:-2:0:3)$ and $\mathbf q=(-8:1:3:0)$. If we treat these as column vectors, the Plücker matrix of this line is $\mathcal L = \mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T$. The intersection of this line with a plane $\mathbf\pi$ is then given by $$\mathcal L\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T)\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf q)\mathbf p - (\mathbf\pi^T\mathbf p)\mathbf q.$$ This vanishes iff the line represented by $\mathcal L$ lies on $\mathbf\pi$. For the third plane, $\mathbf\pi = (0:3:-1:-k)$, for which $$\mathcal L\mathbf\pi = (k+2)\begin{bmatrix}-24\\3\\9\\0\end{bmatrix},$$ which vanishes when $k=-2$ as you determined by other means.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. Relevant and concise. It seems that my textbook and GeoGebra led me to second-guess myself but now I know the answer. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiplying your first equation by $$-1$$ and adding to the second we get
$$-8y-2z=-4$$ multiplying the last equation by $$-2$$ and adding to the equation above we obtain
$$-14y=-4-2k$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this method gets a different result from mine?

Comment: I have used the GAUSS method to solve this System.